# Hashicorp Nomad: Can't request Vault token for terminal allocation

Tags: vault, nomad, hashicorp

I have a jobspec file with multiple tasks. One of which is a "poststop" task.
To be able to inject secrets from Vault, I defined the vault stanza on the task group level. The main task runs fine. However the poststop task fails with

`"Can't request Vault token for terminal allocation"` .

Any way to get around this problem, and inject secret into the template of the poststop task?
My jobspec file:
job "my-task" {

```
  group "my-task-group" {

   vault {
      policies = ["my-policy-name"]
      env      = true
   }


   task "main-task" {

     service {
       name = "my-service"
     }

     driver = "docker"
     user = "root"

      config {
        image = "..."
        ...
      }

      template {
        data = <<EOF
{% raw %}{{with secret "secrets/data/foo/bar/my-secret-this-works-fine"}}{{.Data.data.my_secret}}{{end}}{% endraw %} 
EOF

        destination = "local/works-fine.txt"

      }

    }

    task "task-that-fails" {

        lifecycle {
          hook = "poststop"
          sidecar = false
        }

        driver = "exec"

        template {

           data = <<EOF
{% raw %}{{with secret "secrets/data/foo/bar/my-secret-this-fails"}}{{.Data.data.my_secret_fails}}{{end}}{% endraw %} 
EOF
           destination = "local/will-fail.txt"

        }

        config {
          command = "bash"
          args = ["..."]
        }

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: can this help https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/issues/9610 ?